# Python groupby itertools method

Tags: python

I am new to python programing.I am unable to create the following code:

Define a function even_or_odd, which takes an integer as input and returns the string even and odd, if the given number is even and odd respectively.
Categorise the numbers of list n = [10, 14, 16, 22, 9, 3 , 37] into two groups namely even and odd based on above defined function.
Hint : Use groupby method of itertools module.
Iterate over the obtained groupby object and print it's group name and list of elements associated with a group.

I have tried below code:

```
import itertools
def even_or_odd(n):
    if n%2==0:
        return 'even'
    else:
        return 'odd'
group=[]
uniquekeys=[]
n = [10, 14, 16, 22, 9, 3 , 37]
for k,g in itertools.groupby(n, even_or_odd(n)):
    groups.append(list(g))    
    uniquekeys.append(k)

It is giving "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int' "
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions about homework question. As a side note, using groupby to 'categorize' the numbers sounds like a strange idea, and would work here only because the odd and even numbers already are grouped...

Comment: I have updated my attempt above, but it is giving me TypeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to pass `itertools.groupby` `even_or_odd` you call it with `n`. `even_or_odd` takes an `int`, but `n` is a list. Just change it to `itertools.groupby(n, even_or_odd)` 
Also you append to `groups` when I think you mean `group`.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion was valuable and code ran fine.

Comment: @RohiTheGr8 If it is acceptable you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it. That way the question will appear as answered.